# "I've just finished packing your package and {ordered/ordering} a courier..." -- which is correct "ordered" or "ordering"?

Tags: sentence-construction, present-perfect, sequence-of-tenses

I'm having a discussion with my partner about the use of correct wording in the sentence. As we are both foreigners and quite stubborn, we can not decide which version is more native and natural.

> I’ve just finished packing your parcel and **ordered** DHL courier for tomorrow.

or

> I’ve just finished packing your parcel and **ordering** DHL courier
> for tomorrow.

Comment: As an aside, *courier* is a countable word, so it needs a determiner, like "**a** DHL courier".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct. They have slightly different structures. I've bracketed portions to show the difference in structure.

> I’ve just [finished packing your parcel] and [ordered DHL courier for tomorrow].

This means I've just **done** two things:

- *finish packing* your parcel
- *order* DHL courier for tomorrow

It could be rephrased: "*I've just finished packing your parcel. I've just **ordered** DHL courier for tomorrow.*

> I’ve just finished [packing your parcel] and [ordering DHL courier for tomorrow].

This means I've just **finished doing** two things:

- *pack* your parcel
- *order* DHL courier for tomorrow

It could be rephrased: "*I've just finished packing your parcel. I've just **finished ordering** DHL courier for tomorrow.*

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical, but to my ears,your first sentence (with *ordered*) is a little unnatural: with that choice (coordinating *ordered* with *finished packing*) I would expect to hear *I've* repeated.

But *I've finished packing ... and I've ordered* and *I've finished packing ... and ordering* sound equally natural to me, depending on whether you're thinking of "ordering" as a unitary action that you've either done or not done, or as a continuing action that it makes sense to "finish".